# Embed remote desktop in browser

Tags: asp.net, activex, cross-browser, embed, remote-desktop

I would like to embed a Remote Desktop session within my browser. I must use remote desktop because my clients can't install any additional software on the server.

Here are some problems that I can already foresee:

1) I believe that I can embed an RDP ActiveX control, but then all I could support is IE. And even then, IE lockdown may forbid ActiveX controls.

2) I don't know anything about Apple computers, but I presume that they don't inherently run RDP?

3) I think there are ways to run RDP through a Java control. I don't have experience to know if this is a good or bad idea. I suppose that Java may even be disabled on some browsers, but don't know if this is a common case?

So, what options have I got here to make this work reliably? I presume that I may need some default options (ie ActiveX), and then some fallback options (ie Java), and code to identify the correct option each time.

Comment: Here is a relevant Google search: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=remote+desktop+in+browser&oq=remote+desktop+in+browser&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i5j0i5i30.6109.12540.0.12687.32.32.0.0.0.0.115.2544.29j3.32.0.les%3Beqn%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D2%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue..0.0...1c.1.ELGjy25RKIE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c19dece5f44ab15&bpcl=38625945&biw=1366&bih=631

Answer (score 0):

With regards to #2, Microsoft has created a RDP client for OS X, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6573f9f1-8ae1-4da9-ab5c-f8457ecdaf2d&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

How about [properJavaRDP](http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/) - RDP client in java. According to the site, works on Windows, Linux and OS X. It looks like it's shipped as a regular JAR - you might repackage it as a Java Web Start app for deployment from a browser, or even a (signed) applet. (Applet will need to be signed to connect to any arbitrary host.)

Comment: This looks quite good, but unfortunately it doesn't look like I can legally use it in a commercial application (without releasing my code)...

Comment: Ok. In future please include as much detail in your question as possible. Commercial use (close-source) is quite an important restriction. You might be able to contact the author and obtain a commercial licence. Many GPL projects are dual-licensed.

Comment: Also, you should check the licence carefully. What source do you think you need to release? The GPL software is only used on the webpage. You may only need to open source the webpage that is using - and the source is already available anyway (the page is the source.) I think more importantly is providing a link to comply with the GPL that provides a download link with the software and source code, and you can simply link to sourceforge. I'm assuming the webpage is hosted. If you're shipping a server and including an rdp client as part of that then that's a different matter.

Comment: It looks like it's a cross-platform client for Windows terminal services. Is there a version that allows remote access to any operating system (not just Windows?)